# Azure DevOps Make a merge during pipeline

Tags: git, azure-devops, cicd

I am a beginner in Azure devops and I would like to make a merge (without deleting my old branch) on the master during a pipeline.
I have a US 89 development branch. In this one, I have developed a new feature. I make a pull request on my development branch.
I have to make changes on the files of my develop branch (change of link).
For this, I use a pipeline and modify my files with a command.
I would like these loads to be directly added to my master branch.

I tried to create an artifact and deploy it but I can't find the trick.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a best practice to push on your repository through your build pipeline.

However you can perform git commands from a `powershell` or a `cmd` task on Azure Devops. Depending on where your source control is located you will need a user that can interact with Github, or a PAT for Azure Devops git repository.

An example with powershell for Github is the below. If you have an Azure Devops repo you just change the format of push to `https://PAT@repourl/repository.git`

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Merge git changes
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      git config user.email "youremail"
      git config user.name "yourname"
      git fetch
      // edit files
      git add --all
      git commit -m "yourmessage"
      git push https://username:PAT@github.com/username/repository.git
```

Comment: OK I will try that but i have a question. With you push, do you directly push the code in the Master branch ?

Comment: @GuyDupont you can append a git checkout command also and specify the current branch on which you work

Comment: OK i try this. I willq send you my results. Thanks @GeralexGR

Comment: @GuyDupont do not forget to mark the question as solved, if the solution solves your problem.

Comment: What is the PAT in the link use for the publish pls ?

Comment: @GuyDupont it is a personal access token. Make a research and familiarize with Azure Devops as you need to understand some concepts to make this work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page